# How to mock a complex react component with props using Jest/ react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
import {ActualComponent} from "mycomponentlibrary";

//Below is my Mock component which I want to use as mock.
const MockComponent = props => {
    const selectedUser = {
        name: "User1",
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{props.dialogTitle}</div>
            <button onClick={() => props.onSelect(selectedUser)}>{"Select"}</button>
        </div>
    );
};

//below is how am trying to mock
    jest.doMock("mycomponentlibrary", () => () => {
        return {
            __esModule: true,
            ActualComponent: jest.fn(() => MockComponent),
        };
    });
```

But I see that my tests are failing and in logs I see that actual component is being used instead of mock.

Is there anything which am doing wrong.

Note: `ActualComponent` is not a default export and I dont want to mock other components from `"mycomponentlibrary"`

Comment: Do you need the duplicated arrow function?

Comment: read some where that I need to use the duplicate arrow function, but it dint work with both single and double arrow function.

Comment: [The docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) have a different pattern than what you're using. What are you trying to test?

Answer (score 0):

```
jest.mock("mycomponentlibrary", () => {
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        ActualComponent: () => MockComponent
    };
};
```

Instead of doMock using mock is sufficient in this case.

Also, do not use jest.fn() to wrap your mocked component unless you want to spy on it.